# Can you tell me why I am displaying backward?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#include "IList.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


//how to open a file
ifstream inf(argv[1]);
IList t;
int integer;



//reading integer from text file.
inf >> integer;

//Up untill the end of file, it is going to insert integer to the
 list and read integer from text file again.

while(!inf.eof())
{
    t.insert(integer, 0);
    inf >> integer;
}
//displaying the list
t.display(cout);




return 0;
}
```

******reference************

```
List.h

void display(ostream & out) const;
//Display a list.

//Precondition: The ostream out is open.

//Postcondition: The list represented by this List object has been
//inserted into out.


void insert(ElementType item, int pos);
//Insert a value into the list at a given position.

//Precondition: item is the value to be inserted; there is room in 
//the array (mySize < CAPACITY); and the position satisfies
//0 <= pos <= mySize.

//Postcondition: item has been inserted into the list at the position 
//determined by pos (provided there is room and pos is a legal 
//position).



List.cpp



void IList::display(ostream & out) const
{
for (int i = 0; i < mySize; i++)
 out << myArray[i] << "  ";
}




void IList::insert(ElementType item, int pos)
{
if (mySize == myCapacity)
{
  cerr << "*** No space for list element -- terminating "
          "execution ***\n";
  exit(1);
}
if (pos < 0 || pos > mySize)
{
  cerr << "*** Illegal location to insert -- " << pos 
       << ".  List unchanged. ***\n";
  return;
}

// First shift array elements right to make room for item

for(int i = mySize; i > pos; i--)
  myArray[i] = myArray[i - 1];

// Now insert item at position pos and increase list size  
myArray[pos] = item;
mySize++;
}
```

For the reference, I added order of Display / Insert.

Display / Insert in IList.h

Display / Insert in IList.cpp

I do not know where I printed backward or inserted backward.

Can you tell me how I do them in forward, please?

Comment: If you [explain your code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), your rubber duck should be able to answer this question for you. If your rubber duck is on vacation, there's a very useful tool on your computer called a "debugger". Using this amazing tool you can step through your code, one line at a time, and examine the contents of all variables; and understand why, and how, your code works the way it is. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: #include "IList.h" , but files: List.h and List.cpp... may be #include "List.h"

Answer (score 3):

You are always inserting in the beginning of your list:

```
t.insert(integer, 0);
```

Let's say you have numbers 1 and 2. You insert 1 first, your list becomes {1}. Then you insert 2 in the beginning, and now your list contains {2, 1}. You see?